# Displaying custom field on OpenCart product page

Tags: php, opencart

I added a new field in the product table of OpenCart called MAP. I was able to add it to the admin no problem but I'm having trouble getting the value to the product page to display.

I would show my code but I feel like I was so far off so I deleted my additions. I'm using version 1.5.6.4.

If someone would help me out with the appropriate code for the MVC that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You will call MAP field through following opencart structure.

In Model file **catalog/model/catalog/product.php** add field in the array of

```
public function getProduct($product_id) {
```

> 'map'              => $query->row['map'],

in Controller file **catalog/controller/product/product.php** add following code after `if ($product_info) {` condition

```
$this->data['map'] = $product_info['map'];
```

And last you will add MAP field under template file **catalog/view/theme/*/template/product/product.tpl**

```
<span>MAP</span> <?php echo $map; ?><br />
```

Cheers